# mingw c compile

Tags: c, compilation, mingw

I am trying to compile a very simple C program. Installed MinGW using auto installer, then added **C:\MinGW\bin** on my environment variable.

***test.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello");
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this:

> gcc test.c -o test.exe

But I got this error,

> test.c: In function 'main': test.c:5:12: warning: character constant
>   too long for its type [enabled by defau lt] test.c:5:5: warning:
>   passing argument 1 of 'printf' makes pointer from integer w ithout a
>   cast [enabled by default]
>   c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../include/stdio.h:294:37:
>   note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'int'

Pardon for being noob, trying to learn something worthy. Thanks!

Comment: Which text editor are you using? Could it be replacing double quotes with single quotes?

Comment: You code compiles on my desktop minGW.   Something else is going on, there may be unprintable characters embedded or as Dmitri says your editor is playing unfair.

Comment: Notepad++, oh I see now why. But question, it does compile now, why I doesn't see any outputs?

Comment: As @DmitriChubarov said, add a newline to the printf.

Comment: @Defensor: standard output is normally buffered, so you either need to add a `\n` to your string (`"Hello\n"`) to force a line feed or add the line `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message that you are getting matches exactly the error message that GCC would generate for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf('Hello');
  return 0;
}
```

That is the double quotes got replaced with single quotes.

Use notepad or better Notepad++ to check what is going on.

Comment: Notepad++, oh I see now why. But question, it does compile now, why I doesn't see any outputs?

Comment: Not sure why there is no output. Try to replace `"Hello"` with `"Hello\n"`. See if this changes anything.

Comment: I did but still no output. It just creates an .exe file, I tried to double click it but it just pop for a second.

Comment: @Defensor open a `cmd` window and run your .exe file from the command line.

Comment: @tree what do you mean? But I am running it in the console.

Comment: That's exactly where I am now.

Comment: You should not double click it. You mentioned double clicking.

Comment: you compiled in a DOS Prompt box right? Black background window with a C:\> type prompt? If so then to run the program type test.exe  <enter>, You should then see your output if run from the directory in which you compiled your program.

Comment: I just mentioned it because I tried to double click it. But the moment I ask the question I am in the console. Above all, it now works. Gracias!

Comment: JimNorton & Dmitri - Great! That exactly what I just did seconds earlier your comment. Gracias.